# Remove string after a certain character

Tags: excel, vba

i'm trying to move words after the first space from 30th character in a string to the next row(i+1) added and remove those words moved to the next row from the current row(i). The code is giving **Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument error** message at **Cells(i, 1).Value = Left(Cells(i, 1), InStr(30, Cells(i, 1), " ") - 1)** line.

```
Sub TextLimit_02()

Dim i As Long
Dim CelLen As Long

 For i = 1 To 50

 CelLen = Len(Cells(i, 1))

  If CelLen > 40 Then

  Rows(i + 1).Insert

  Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = Mid(Cells(i, 1), InStr(30, Cells(i, 1), " ") + 1, Len(Cells(i, 
  1).Value) - InStr(30, Cells(i, 1), " "))

  Cells(i, 1).Value = Left(Cells(i, 1), InStr(30, Cells(i, 1), " ") - 1)

 Else

 End If

Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: Most likely `InStr(30, Cells(i, 1), " ")` is returning `0`.

Comment: You need to step through it and check your variables and each part that is calculating too.  It's basic debugging that you need to be able to do. It might be easier to break apart that long line into pieces so that you can see where the problem is. Without any data, all anyone here can do is guess.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't account for the possibility that in a string longer than 40, there are no spaces after position 30.

Breaking the logic down into steps makes it easy to detect this, and possibly add more code to deal with it

```vb
Sub TextLimit_02()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim CelLen As Long
    Dim idx As Long
    Dim CellString As String
    Dim LeftPart As String
    Dim RightPart As String
    
    For i = 1 To 50
        CellString = Cells(i, 1).Value2
        CelLen = Len(CellString)
        If CelLen > 40 Then
            idx = InStr(30, CellString, " ")
            If idx > 0 Then
                Rows(i + 1).Insert
                LeftPart = Left$(CellString, idx - 1)
                RightPart = Mid$(CellString, idx + 1)
                Cells(i, 1) = LeftPart
                Cells(i + 1, 1) = RightPart

                If idx > 40 Then
                    ' there remains >40 characters in Cells(i, 1)
                End If
            Else
                ' No spaces after position 30.  Cells(i, 1) remains longer than 40
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Note that if you split a lot of strings, your data may end up spanning past row 50.  With `For i = 1 to 50` you will miss processing some string in that case.

Answer (score 0):

This code should do what you intend. Please test it and let me know what it does wrong.

```
Sub TextLimit_02()
    ' 269
    
    Dim Txt     As String               ' text
    Dim Tail    As String               ' tail end of Txt to be moved
    Dim p       As Long                 ' position of character in string
    Dim R       As Long                 ' loop counter: rows

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ' start from the end of column A to 2nd row
    For R = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
        Txt = Trim(Cells(R, "A").Value)         ' remove leading/trailing blanks
        p = InStr(Mid(Txt, 30), " ")
        Tail = Trim(Mid(Txt, p + 30))           ' in case of double space
        If Len(Tail) Then                       ' skip if no Tail
            Cells(R, "A").Value = Left(Txt, p + 29)
            Rows(R + 1).Insert
            Cells(R + 1, "A").Value = Tail
        End If
    Next R
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
Sub WrapText()
    Const MIN_CARRY_POS = 30, MAX_LEN = 40, CARRY_SYMBOL = " "  'preferences
    Dim cl As Range, txt As String, pos As Long, slice As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set cl = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1")
    Do  'main row loop
        txt = RTrim(cl.Text)
        Select Case Len(txt)
            Case 0: Exit Do
            Case Is > MAX_LEN
                Do While Len(txt) > MAX_LEN 'a nested loop to process text that needs to be carried over
                    pos = InStr(MIN_CARRY_POS, txt, CARRY_SYMBOL)
                    If pos < 1 Then pos = MAX_LEN   'if no CARRY_SYMBOL after MIN_CARRY_POS then cut the string at MAX_LEN
                    slice = WorksheetFunction.Min(pos, MAX_LEN)
                    cl.Insert xlDown
                    cl.Offset(-1).Value = Mid(txt, 1, slice)   'output the head
                    txt = LTrim(Mid(txt, slice + 1))    'get the rest of the txt
                Loop
                cl.Value = txt 'output the rest <= MAX_LEN
        End Select
        Set cl = cl.Offset(1)   'move to the next row
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

**Before**
[image]

**After**
[image]